# Node.js & npm: How can I create custom npm cli commands?

Tags: node.js, npm

Say for example that I quite often use `npm list -g -depth 0` as command, and I'd like to alias it with `npm listC` or `npm list -c1`.

How do I do that?

Comment: In addition to the answer given by duncanhall below, here's a blog post I found helpful when starting out with NPM scripts - they're a lot more flexible than you might first imagine: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [npm scripts](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to create shortcuts for custom commands.

In your `package.json` you might have:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "listC": "npm list -g depth 0"
    }
}
```

And you could then run it with `npm run listC`.